# How do I fix this 'Restore of database AdventureWorks2014 failed' permanently?

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

When I try to restore AdventureWorks2014, I get this

> 'Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in
> use.(Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)'

Of course there is no query window open. I do not have this issue with other databases. The only difference that I found between AdventureWorks2014 and the rest of my databases is compatibility level, 2014 and 2019 respectively. But it was not the solution. I checked the Microsoft link provided with error message which took me to Microsoft home page. I could not find what I was looking for in Documentation. So I went around by setting the database offline or checking 'Close existing connections to destination database' option. Both of them works but I would like to find a permanent solution. Is there one?

Comment: Do you have AdventureWorks2014 (or any of its child objects) selected in the SSMS Object Explorer panel? That's enough to hold an open connection to the database. You could also use `sp_who` or `sp_who2` to find any open connections to that database and then `kill _spid_` them.

Comment: Would that fail restore? I just tried with another db which I selected so there was - sign in front of that db in Explorer. It restored just fine. However, I also tried that with AdventureWorks2014 and made sure that it was not selected, I was able to restore without putting it offline or closing any connection. So I will keep that in mind next time. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, any open connection from anywhere is enough to fail a restore.

Comment: All my trainings taught me about closing down the query windows not the Explorer. Unfortunately it has always worked until now. Thank you. Learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Database to SINGLE_USER before the RESTOE:

```
USE master
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2014 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
RESTORE AdventureWorks2014.....
```

Comment: I can't try because I do not have the same issue anymore. But is it same as setting db offline?

Comment: No, it sets the database in SINGLE_USER-mode with killing all connections on the database. So you should execute the Restore immediately afterwards, so that the process(es) that had the connection to the database cannot reestablish a connection (if that process(es) is (are) reconnectable)

Comment: FWIW, I've had mixed luck with this approach. Single user is just that - it allows one user in the database. In a busy system, that may or may not be you! Instead, I like to set the database offline (with `rollback immediate` like you're doing) and then issue the restore.

Answer (score 0):

Something was blocking your database restore. To find out what, issue the restore as T-SQL (even if you're going through some sort of UI, script it out so you can run it by hand) in one window and note the SPID for that window. If you don't know where to find that in your UI of choice (my guess is that you're using SSMS, but maybe not!), you can issue a query of `SELECT @@SPID` to find it. Before starting up your restore, open another window/session and get this query ready to run:

```
select *
from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
where session_id = «spid from your restore session»;
```

Kick off your restore and then run the above query to see what is blocking.

Comment: Thank you. That's great. I made a note and definitely will try it next time it happens!